# GIGABYTE AB350 Gaming poorly configurable BIOS?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios

I recently purchased the AB350 Gaming (not Gaming 3) board, and I was dismayed to discover that the BIOS appears to be locked into what seems like an 'easy mode', with more than half the features I see on any screenshot, or even listen in the manual missing. For example, this is what my CPU frequency settings screen looks like:

[image: GIGABYTE AB350 Gaming MIT CPU frequency screen]

I already flashed the BIOS to the newest version at this time. Is there anything else I can do to 'unlock' more settings, or did I just pick a bad board ?

Options I am missing that I have seen in the manual include System Memory Multiplier, Memory Frequency, and on various screenshots I saw that there was an entire page of options.

Comment: All expected options are present as mentioned in the manual on page 21/22. What options do you believe to be missing?

Comment: @DanielB: Host Clock Value, Core Performance Boost Ratio, C6 Mode, System Memory Multiplier, Memory Frequency, and on various screenshots I saw a lot more options

Comment: The memory frequency being on this page is probably a mistake in the manual. It simply does not belong on this page. Some items were renamed, like “C6 Mode” → “Global C-state Control”.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not surprised your ASUS motherboard looks nothing like my GIGABYTE mainboard ;)

Answer (score 1):

For the particular settings page you show, for many settings the manual marks features with "(Note)" in superscript and the footnote says "This item is only present when you install a CPU that supports this feature".

For example, your screen does not show "Core performance boost ratio" and "Turbo Performance boost" presumably because your CPU does not support it.

Comment: While that is true for those two items, it is not for the other items I'm missing, and it was my understanding that my processor, an AMD Ryzen 7 1700, did support both CPBR and TPB.

Comment: @Torque - How about you update your question and provide that information. That is important information to have.